# Flutter dart issue - callback method not returning the latest value of the variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling this dart method which is on a different class on the press of a button. The codeSent value at first return false and then later returns true.

```
class Authenticate {
    bool codeSent = false;
    bool get isCodeSent {
      return this.codeSent;
    }
    Future<bool> signInWithPhone(String phone, BuildContext context) async {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phone,
          codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
            this.codeSent = true;
            print('inside: $this.codeSent');
          },
        );
        print(this.codeSent);
        return this.codeSent;
    }
}
```

This is the way I am calling the above method from the widget class on the press of a button. The codeSent value always returns false after the below callback is preformed even when it is set to true the second time it is called. How do I get the latest value of the codeSent variable so that I would be able to perform a UI update?

```
  bool codeSent = false;
  Authenticate auth = Authenticate();
  ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
          auth.signInWithPhone(phone, context).then((result) => {
          setState(() => this.codeSent = result),
    });
  },
  child: Text('Verify'),
 )
```

UPDATE As per James comment -

```
Restarted application in 366ms.
flutter: false
flutter: inside: true
```

Expected result should the final return value should be equal to the value of the inside print statement.

Comment: Are you getting "inside" printed on the console? if yes, try removing `this` keyword

Comment: You have a bunch of debugging `print` statements.  What did they print?  This also isn't your actual code (`class` is miscapitalized as `Class, you refer to `auth.isCodeSent` which is not defined).  Also, you use `(...) => { setState(...), }`, which is wrong: it creates an anonymous function that returns a `Set`.

Comment: @BurakCabadan Yes I am getting inside the print statements. The print statements inside the method returns false first and then true after, which means it runs the return statement first which returns false and then it runs the print statements inside the codeSent method

Comment: @jamesdlin missed to add the auth.isCodeSent declaration, added it now. Didn't get what you mentioned about setState. Could you provide me with some examples on what you meant?

Comment: `() => x` is an anonymous function that returns `x`. `() => { x }` is an anonymous function that returns a `Set` containing `x`.  Either remove the curly braces or remove the `=>`; don't use both.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin for the detailed explanation, I have changed my code accordingly. But regarding the actual issue, that still seems unresolved.

Comment: That you use `this.codeSent` in some places but just `codeSent` in others is weirdly inconsistent and opens the door to be referring to two different variables.  Please fix that too.  Also, instead of using `print` on bare `bool` values, you should use things like `print('inside: $codeSent')` so that there's less ambiguity about which line of output was printed by which line of code.  It should not be possible for the "inside" code to print `false`.  Please update your question with the updated code and with the exact output that you get.

Comment: @jamesdlin , I have updated my code with the changes you mentioned, ran it and added the results to the post as well.

Comment: Anybody who could help me out with this?